# How to catch divide-by-zero error in Visual Studio 2008 C++?

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2008, try-catch

How can I catch a divide-by-zero error (and not other errors; and to be able to access exception information) in Visual Studio 2008 C++?

I tried this:

```
try {
  int j=0;
  int i= 1/j;//actually, we call a DLL here, which has divide-by-zero
} catch(std::exception& e){
  printf("%s %s\n", e.what()); 
}  catch(...){
  printf("generic exception");
}
```

But this goes to the generic ... catch block. I understand that the MS-specific __try  may  be useful here, but I'd prefer standard C++, and in any case I have destructors which prevent the use of __try.

CLARIFICATION: The code above is simplified for discussion purposes. Actually, the divide-by-zero is a bug which occurs deep in a third-party DLL for which I do not have the source code. The error depends on the parameter (a handle to a complex structure) which I pass to the library, but not in any obvious way. So, I want to be able to recover gracefully.

Comment: "I'd prefer standard C++" then you must prefer not to divide by zero, since that's undefined behaviour. It's platform-specific that it throws an exception at all, so it's no great imposition if the means of catching it is also platform-specific. On platforms where divide-by-zero doesn't throw, you cannot recover from this bug in the dll, so you don't need a platform-independent means of recovery.

Comment: @Steve Jessop In the real example, the divide-by-zero  is deep in a DLL for which I do not have the source code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you can't simply fix the cause of the exception generating code (perhaps because you don't have the source code to that particular library and perhaps because you can't adjust the input params before they cause a problem).

You have to jump through some hoops to make this work as you'd like but it can be done.

First you need to install a Structured Exception Handling translation function by calling  `_set_se_translator()` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5(VS.80).aspx)) then you can examine the code that you're passed when an SEH exception occurs and throw an appropriate C++ exception.

```
void CSEHException::Translator::trans_func(
    unsigned int code, 
    EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pPointers)
{
   switch (code)
   {
       case FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO : 
          throw CMyFunkyDivideByZeroException(code, pPointers);
       break;
   }

   // general C++ SEH exception for things we don't need to handle separately....
   throw CSEHException(code, pPointers);
}
```

Then you can simply catch your `CMyFunkyDivideByZeroException()` in C++ in the normal way.

Note that you need to install your exception translation function on every thread that you want exceptions translated.

Comment: Just want to mention that `_set_se_translator` works on a per-thread basis and is only useful if you control the creation of _all threads_. Most likely this falls on your feet when calling DLLs. You simply cannot translate their SEHs. For example, an Excel C AddIn DLL may therefore easily crash the whole Excel process. Only a `catch(...)` block will catch them - but neither you nor Excel knows which SEH was catched. It could be an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` (alias `SIGSEGV` on other OSs) in which case you're doomed anyway. I think `_set_se_translator` creates a false feeling of security.

Comment: Andreas, that's true, but if you're on a thread that you don't own then you can wrap your function in an SEH exception handler and deal with it as a normal SEH exception and therefore you DO know the type of exception that you caught (you have to jump through hoops and maybe create a extra shim function if you want to catch SEH exceptions in a function that also deals with C++ exceptions). Oh and `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` isn't game over, necessarily - the OS is simply telling you that you can't access the memory.

Comment: I meant in case of `catch(...)` naturally you don't know what the type is. Anyway... unless your program is a debugger, spyware or a virus, why would you ever access memory you don't own? In most cases the program is bad. Even in case of a "harmless" NULL pointer access the program can't continue because it will crash again.

Comment: I'm not saying that you would WANT to access memory that you don't own, just that "you're doomed anyway" is a bit strong, since you can always create a mini dump and possibly still shut down cleanly in many cases.

Comment: This will work for you, since you are already getting the exceptions, but for anyone trying to use this and not getting anything, you might have to enable floating point exceptions with some ugly code. Here is an example (this is what we use in VS2015, sorry for the bad formatting):                                                     // set up floating point divide by zero exceptions
    _clearfp();

    uint32 control_word = 0;
    _controlfp_s(&control_word, _MCW_EM, _MCW_EM);
    _controlfp_s(0, ~(uint32)
        (_EM_UNDERFLOW | _EM_OVERFLOW | _EM_ZERODIVIDE | _EM_INVALID), _MCW_EM);

Answer (score 9):

C++ does not handle divide-by-zero as an exception, per-se.

Quoting Stroustrup:

> "low-level events, such as arithmetic
>   overflows and divide by zero, are
>   assumed to be handled by a dedicated
>   lower-level mechanism rather than by
>   exceptions. This enables C++ to match
>   the behaviour of other languages when
>   it comes to arithmetic. It also avoids
>   the problems that occur on heavily
>   pipelined architectures where events
>   such as divide by zero are
>   asynchronous."

*"The Design and Evolution of C++" (Addison Wesley, 1994)*

In any case, exceptions are **never** a replacement for proper precondition handling.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct. But I cannot handle the precondition, since the divide-by-zero is a bug which occurs deep in a third-party DLL for which I do not have the source code. (The code I gave above was (over)simplified for discussion purposes.) I need to recover gracefully from the bug.

Answer (score 9):

To catch divide by zero exceptions in Visual C++ try->catch (...) just enable /EHa option in project settings. See **Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Modify the Enable C++ Exceptions to "Yes With SEH Exceptions"**. That's it!

See details here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

You can either use structured exception handling (using __try etc.) or you can install a structured exception handler translator: [_set_se_translator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5(VS.80).aspx)

Both of these are operating system specific.

Comment: Link is now bad, here's a new one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-se-translator

Answer (score 3):

You can not do that using standard C++ as it is not standard C++ exception. It's a structured exception. For the standard C++ exception somebody has to do a `throw exception;` from the code.

Answer (score 2):

Why not check for this before? The performance will be trivial for a simple `j == 0` compared to context-switching for exception handling.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct. But I cannot handle the precondition, since the divide-by-zero is a bug which occurs deep in a third-party DLL for which I do not have the source code. (The code I gave above was (over)simplified for discussion purposes.) I need to recover gracefully from the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
try
{ 
  const int j=0;
  if (j == 0) { throw std::exception("j was 0"); } 
  const int i= 1/j;    
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{ 
  printf("%s %s\n", e.what());  
}
catch(...)
{ 
  printf("generic exception"); 
}
```

Of course, if you're OK doing this without exceptions, you could do:

```
const int j = 0;
if (j == 0)
{
  /* do something about the bad pre-condition here */
}
else
{
  const int i = 1 / j;
}
```

Edit in response to clarification: you'll have to figure out what input it is that you're handing the third party that causes them to divide by zero before-hand, and handle that before ever calling their function.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be to use safe object oriented wrappers like [SafeInt](http://safeint.codeplex.com/). It also [seems to be integrated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd570021%28VS.100%29.aspx) in Visual Studio 2010.

*update:*
If the division-by-zero happens in third party code your only option is SEH or something equivalent as [answered by Seb Rose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832809/how-to-catch-divide-by-zero-error-in-visual-studio-2008-c/1832821#1832821)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [try-except Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-except-statement?view=vs-2019).
But, don't forget that you need to set it for each thread.